# Nitrogen over Yaws set cookie throws exception

Tags: erlang, yaws, nitrogen

I've installed Nitrogen over Yaws (**Nitrogen 2.4.0, Yaws 2.0.8, ERTS 13.2 - R25**).

When I try `http://0.0.0.0:8000/`I get **Internal server error**. When I check in the console I get this error.

```
{error,first_request,
    {url,"b_server/"},
    {throw,
        {badarg,same_site},
        [{yaws_api,cookie_option,2,[{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,725}]},
         {yaws_api,'-set_cookie/3-fun-0-',2,
             [{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,734}]},
         {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1350}]},
         {yaws_api,set_cookie,3,[{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,733}]},
         {yaws_simple_bridge,'-assemble_headers/1-lc$^0/1-1-',1,
             [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
              {line,215}]},
         {yaws_simple_bridge,assemble_headers,1,
             [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
              {line,215}]},
         {yaws_simple_bridge,build_response,2,
             [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
              {line,161}]},
         {wf_core,run,0,[{file,"src/wf_core.erl"},{line,23}]}]}}
```

```
Crash Handler Crashed:
{throw,{badarg,same_site},
       [{yaws_api,cookie_option,2,[{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,725}]},
        {yaws_api,'-set_cookie/3-fun-0-',2,
                  [{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,734}]},
        {lists,foldl,3,[{file,"lists.erl"},{line,1350}]},
        {yaws_api,set_cookie,3,[{file,"src/yaws_api.erl"},{line,733}]},
        {yaws_simple_bridge,'-assemble_headers/1-lc$^0/1-1-',1,
                            [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
                             {line,215}]},
        {yaws_simple_bridge,assemble_headers,1,
                            [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
                             {line,215}]},
        {yaws_simple_bridge,build_response,2,
                            [{file,"src/yaws_bridge_modules/yaws_simple_bridge.erl"},
                             {line,161}]},
        {wf_core,run_crash,4,[{file,"src/wf_core.erl"},{line,46}]}]}
```

This is subtle to me! I failed to know what could be causing it.

Answer (score 2):

Yaws 2.0.8 doesn't have `SameSite` cookie support. You'll need at least version 2.1.0, or better yet, the [current release, 2.1.1](https://github.com/erlyaws/yaws/releases/tag/yaws-2.1.1).